# Group characters by number of occurrences in a string with Itertools

Tags: rust

I have two approaches to grouping characters by the number of occurrences in a string. One of them is using `std::collections::HashMap` and the second one is using [`itertools::Itertools::group_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by). Unfortunately, grouping with `Itertools` gives me undesirable results.

Example input word: `"Barbara"`

Using `std::collections::HashMap`

```
let map1 = word.to_lowercase()
    .chars()
    .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, c| {
        *acc.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
        acc
    });
```

**Result `{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'r': 2}`**

And using `itertools::Itertools::group_by`

```
let map2: HashMap<char, u32> = word.to_lowercase()
    .chars()
    .group_by(|&x| x)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(k, v)| (k, v.count() as u32))
    .collect();
```

**Result `{'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 1}`**

Oddly enough, when the input string has identical characters in succession, `Itertools` takes those characters into account.
The question is, what makes it return different results?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb6f4adb3f39828d97558e241745c250)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`into_group_map_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.into_group_map_by). `group_by` only groups consecutive elements according to the [docs](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by).

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let word = "Barbara";

    let map1 = word
        .to_lowercase()
        .chars()
        .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, c| {
            *acc.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
            acc
        });
    println!("{:?}", map1);

    let map2: HashMap<char, u32> = word
        .to_lowercase()
        .chars()
        .into_group_map_by(|&x| x)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| (k, v.len() as u32))
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", map2);
}
```

Output:

```
{'b': 2, 'a': 3, 'r': 2}
{'b': 2, 'r': 2, 'a': 3}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=792e2e14cb70b00779cdde389938689e)

There's also `into_grouping_map_by`, which can be used for this like:

```rust
let map2: HashMap<char, u32> = word
    .to_lowercase()
    .chars()
    .into_grouping_map_by(|&x| x)
    .fold(0, |acc, _key, _value| acc + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) says (emphasis added):

> ```
> fn group_by<K, F>(self, key: F) -> GroupBy<K, Self, F>
> where
>     Self: Sized,
>     F: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> K,
>     K: PartialEq,
> ```
>
> Return an *iterable* that can group iterator elements. **Consecutive** elements that map to the same key (“runs”), are assigned to the same group.

It only groups consecutive elements. You'll need to sort the characters before calling `group_by`.

```
let map2: HashMap<char, u32> = word.to_lowercase()
    .chars()
    .sorted()
    .group_by(|&x| x)
    ...
```

Output:

```
{'a': 3, 'r': 2, 'b': 2}
{'b': 2, 'a': 3, 'r': 2}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=664697aec90b09a648cf291c00648aaa)

Comment: Both answers are great, but I had to pick one. Yours was more descriptive, but I picked @Dogbert answer, since he also added hints with `into_grouping_map_by` which might be handy for someone seeking for similar answer. Both of your comments combined makes everything super clear. Thank You!